# Notify GCD background thread

Tags: ios, swift

I have 15 GCD background threads that runs 15 parallel workers. While I've seen a lot of examples for sending notification / delegate from background to main thread. I wonder how I can send signal to all 15 threads from the main thread?

Comment: I am smelling [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. We need to see your code to be able to help you.

Comment: Agreed with @ozgur. As described this question does not make sense. This  is not a normal GCD pattern. GCD does not manage things in terms of "background threads" or "parallel workers." It manages queues and blocks, which are a very different approach to the problem. See "Migrating Away from Threads" that explains how to convert thread-based designs to GCD: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW7

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I assume you are talking about queues but not threads, because there is no guarantee that each queue will create separate thread for it's work. If so than you should look to `dispatch_group` topic. If there is not enough power to solve your problem, than check out `NSOperation` queue, it's much more powerful. Hope it helps.